# Is there a better alternative than LIKE for this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve data from a table where there are codes for projects which are identified by the first three numbers, the rest are unique. So, for example, the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM 
TableA
WHERE LEFT(acccode,3) IN ('121','131','141','151','161')
```

Now, I want this condition to be true for all these codes except for one. Say, for the first one, I want it to look four more characters for anything like '121-111%'. How can I alter my `IN` operator there or do I have to just go with a `LIKE` operator with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
TableA
WHERE acccode LIKE '121-111%'
    OR acccode LIKE '131%'...
```

and so on...?

To clarify: codes starting with 121-111, 131, 141, 151, 161 are the ones I want to select.

All columns are `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Better" in what sense?

The `LIKE` version is sargable as you have no leading wildcards and can use index seeks so that is better in that respect.

In this case you could also consider

```
SELECT * FROM 
TableA
WHERE acccode LIKE '1[3-6]1%'
      OR acccode LIKE '121-111%'
```

As a simplification though the fully expanded version might be more efficient.

If you have no useful index you might prefer just using

```
SELECT * FROM 
TableA
WHERE LEFT(acccode,3) IN ('131','141','151','161') 
      OR acccode LIKE '121-111%'
```

Either way it looks as though there is some meaning buried in `acccode` that might be best storing in a separate column.